# Getting $this inside function

Tags: php

I have a function outside of my class, and i'm calling it from inside using `call_user_func`, my problem is that i cant access class inside the function. i need a way to access my class without passing it in arguments, if there was a way to make `$this` work inside the function that would be wonderful.

Any advice other than passing class with argument into function will be appreciated;

```
function test($arg1)
{
    $this->code = 10; // i know $this won't work here, 
                       // but i need a way to change $code 
                       // property from this function without 
                       // passing class into this function by using arguments
}

class MyClass
{
    public $code;
    public function call()
    {
         call_user_func("test", "argument1");
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not possible; `$this` is only available in object contexts.

Comment: Can you add some code? This would be helpful to give you a suggestion of the alternatives.

Comment: Assuming you can't pass in $this as an argument because you can't modify that function, then why does that function need `$this`, and how would it use it? Otherwise, why not modify the function to pass in `$this`? Some more details would help.

Comment: Why can't you add an argument ? Can you move the function inside of the class ? What's the purpose of this function ? If its purpose is to modify only one member of your class, can you pass it by reference as a function parameter instead ?

Comment: @arn read above comment please :)

Comment: a) Do you already make use of the return value of the functions you're calling? b) Does the class "know" which property a function might want to set/alter?

Comment: @Shadow Walker: I'm not sure I understand fully. Could you elaborate in the question text itself? Is the example `test` function an already existing one? Are you trying to add functionality to every call to functions outside your class? If so, can this be done prior to the call_user_func call itself, by your class?

Comment: @JRL yes, i'm adding this functionality to those function which my class loads, actually these functions are something like external methods. i couldn't find a way to attach methods into my class dynamically.

Answer (score 4):

If you can move the function inside of your class, you would be able to call it like this:

```
call_user_func(array($this, 'the_function'));
```

---

If you have PHP5.3, you can use a closure:

```
$that = $this;
$function = function() use ($that) {
    // use $that instead of $this
};
call_user_func($function);
```

---

If you could add an argument, you could do this:

```
call_user_func('the_function', "argument1", $this);
```

---

Pass `$this` as first parameter if the function asks for it:

(If the function has a parameter named `$__this`, pass `$this` as parameter)

```
function the_function($__this, $foo, $bar) {
}

$arguments = array('argument1');

$function = new ReflectionFunction('the_function');
$params = $function->getParameters();
if (count($params) > 0 && $params[0]->name == '__this') {
    array_unshift($arguments, $this);
}

$function->invokeArgs($arguments);
```

---

You could do the same with doc comments:

```
/**
 * @IWantThis
 */
function the_function($__this) {
}

$function = new ReflectionFunction('the_function');
if (preg_match('/@IWantThis/', $function->getDocComment()) { 
    ...
```

Comment: I don't understand who gave it or why but i upvoted you to counteract the down vote. this looks like a very helpful post.

Comment: Idk who down voted, yes that's a great way, but still don't work in my case

Comment: If I correctly understood your problem, the last solution I added may work; this allows your functions to declare that they want `$this` as first param.

Comment: @arn thank you for all of your useful solutions, the problem is most of my functions that will get called from my class have few overloads

Comment: What do you call overloads extactly ? What is the problem with this ?

Answer (score 2):

*Directly* you have two options: Either passing the object to the function *or* the value to the *object*. I have no clue if that *is* the only job the function does, so this might not solve your problem, just showing the alternative as you wrote that passing the object to the function is not an option:

```
function test($arg1)
{
    return 10;
}

class MyClass
{
    public $code;
    public function call()
    {
         $this->code  = call_user_func("test", "argument1");
    }
}
```

If you don't want any of those, you must create some context both, the object and the function, operate in, to connect both with each other.

You can create context statically or dynamically. The first is often related to global variables which can result in hard to maintain code over time, an example:

```
function test($arg1)
{
     global $object;
     $object->code = 10;
}

class MyClass
{
    public $code;
    public function call()
    {
         global $object;
         $object = $this;
         call_user_func("test", "argument1");
         unset($object);
    }
}
```

To create a more dynamical context, you are encapsulating everything into some context:

```
class contextCallback
{
    private $object;
    public function __construct($object)
    {
        $this->object = $object;
    }
    public function test()
    {
        $this->object = 10;
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public $code;
    public function call()
    {
         $callback = new contextCallback($this);
         call_user_func(array($callback, 'test'), "argument1");
         # or:
         $callback->test("argument1");
    }
}
```

However I think then passing `$this` as an argument is much simpler and pretty much the same with far less code. I have no clue why you need `call_user_func` so it stays this abstract.

**Edit:** As another alternative and to decouple from concrete classes, when you only need to set values, consider returning multiple values:

```
function test($arg1)
{         
     $object->code = 10;
     return array($value, $object);
}

class MyClass
{
    public $code;
    public function call()
    {
         list($value, $object) = call_user_func("test", "argument1");
         foreach($object as $var => $value)
             $this->$var = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices. Make the method a method of the `MyClass` object or make the object a parameter of the function.

If you have a function, you want it to do the same thing, *every* time. This means that if the function depends on some state (like the value of `$this`), then you need to find a way to either 1. make it global (not an option here) or 2. pass it in as a parameter.

You don't *need* a `$this` in that function anyway, you need some object which happens to have an attribute named by whatever the contents of `$code` is (I think that is a typo actually. I think you mean `$this->code` not `$this->$code`).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [closure (php 5.3+)](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)  to "pass" the object reference to those functions that need it.
But you'd have to make a difference between "old" functions and "new" extension functions. And the new functions still only have access to public properties/methods of the object.

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    public $code = 0;
    protected $functions=array();

    public function call($fn)
    {
        if ( is_string($fn) && isset($this->functions[$fn]) ) {
            $fn =   $this->functions[$fn];
        }

        if ( !is_callable($fn) ) {
            die('add error handler here');
        }
        $rv = call_user_func($fn, 'argument1');
    }

    public function loadFunctions($file) {
        $fnInit = require $file;
        $fns = $fnInit($this);
        $this->functions = array_merge($this->functions, $fns);
    }
}

$m = new MyClass;
$m->loadFunctions('ext.php');
$m->call('oldFn');
$m->call('foo');
$m->call('bar');
echo 'and now $m->code is: ', $m->code;
```

and as ext.php:

```
<?php
function oldFn($arg) { // that's probably all you have to do atm to have a new "extension function" for your class
    echo "oldFn($arg)\n";
}


return function($obj) { // and that's more or less how the new functions would have to be declared/defined
    return array(
        'foo'=>function($arg1) use($obj) {
            echo "foo($arg1) + code: $obj->code\n";
            $obj->code = 1;
        },
        'bar'=>function($arg1) use($obj) {
            echo "bar($arg1) + code: $obj->code\n";
            $obj->code = 2;
        }
    );
};
```

prints

```
oldFn(argument1)
foo(argument1) + code: 0
bar(argument1) + code: 1
and now $m->code is: 2
```

( if that seems somehow feasible to you I can write a bit more text ...but not right now ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

```
call_user_func("test", array($this,"argument1"));
```

I'm not 100% but you should be able to access it with

```
function test($arg1)
{
    $arg1[0]->code = 10;
}
```

Comment: You don't have to pass `$this` by reference; it already is a reference of the object.

Comment: Passing variables (or objects) by reference is discouraged in PHP, this will throw a `warning` message.

Comment: Yes it will work, but not like you wrote '$' before "code" will cause error here, and about passing object throw a warning, idk I'm doing this without any warning, i have latest version of php 5.3 and i have error_reporting = E_ALL

Answer (score 0):

Would [`runkit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) suit your needs, specifically [`runkit_function_redefine`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php)?