# Ways to avoid singleton when calling a object inside a global function?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I built some the following i18n function which is called several times when rendering view :

```
function e_($text)
{
    $t = Translate::Instance(); 
    vprintf($t->_($text), array_slice(func_get_args(), 1)); // outputs translated text
}
```

Currently, I get the instance of the Translate singleton Class  inside the function.

I've read that dependency injection should be used instead.
But If I do use dependency injection, I will have to pass the Translate object each time into the function, right ?

This would became :

`<?php e_('my text', $this->Translate);`
and not simply `<?php e_('my text'); ?>`

Well I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: No, you shouldn't. Adding more complexity to something that should just wrap `_()` gettext might not be advisable. (And avoiding fixed identifiers is mostly a need around systemic issues of unit testing in PHP sans runkit.)

Comment: I forgot to say: it's not a gettext function but a Zend Translate method that uses .po/.mo gettext files

Comment: Well, yes. That's basically a userland gettext with a cumbersome API. So, good on you that you have a wrapper function for it. But ain't gonna practically exchange the adapter at runtime, nor likely ever at development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you use the `e_` function is actually using an alias. That's fine as long as you can live with it. You don't need to use a singleton to implement an alias:

```
function e_($text)
{
    return $GLOBALS['e_alias']->alias(func_get_args());
}
```

When setting up the view layer, set the dependency:

```
$GLOBALS['e_alias'] = $translate;
```

In application context, set the global variable `$translate`. This will allow you to move away from the singleton (which are liars), and you actually only need a global variable.

Additionally it allows you to test views with the `e_` alias against different translation implementations.

The downside is that you need to manage a list of all these special global variables, like you need to maintain for the global functions like `e_`.

See as well [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7206487/367456) to the [Getting `$this` inside function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7206192/367456) question.

Comment: Got rid of the singleton and used a $GLOBALS as you recommended me, never mind the global haters.

I never used unit testing in PHP, but would this solution solves the unit testing issues that mario mentionned ?

Comment: Let's say, it solves potential testing problems half-way. The global here plays a bit of a role like a small service locator. You don't have static context now, but global context. But it's easier to mock/inject test-doubles in global context than with static. But it is not totally de-coupled so still harder to test. I would say it depends on what you aim for. Just don't start to introduce more functions like this one probably ;). Not using singletons is generally a good idea, not only because of unit testing. They are superfluous in PHP scripts.

Answer (score 0):

True. The reason you would use dependency injection instead is so that you could swap out the translation method for any particular use of `e_()`.

In this particular case, I'm not sure it would be worth it unless you wish to test different translation methods during testing.

One thing you could do to help a little with performance is make `$t` static so that `Translate::Instance()` is only ever called once no matter how many calls to `e_()` are made.